# Htacess Redirect - Wordpress

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I wanna redirect wordpress page to a static page. The urls such as http://domain.com/?p=222 should be redirected to http://domain.com/222.html. For some reason the code from bellow doesn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^?p=(.*)$  http://domain.com/$1.html [NC,L,R=301]
```

Why is it and what is the correct code?

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule` doesn't match query string. Use this rule instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$  /%1.html [L,R=301]
```